# what is the compatible All dependencies to use Amazon Deequ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pom.xml, fasterxml, amazon-deequ

I have written code for amazon Deequ which is failing due to version issue. In my system Spark 2.4.0 is available, can anyone please suggest that which version of Deequ and Scala, fasterxml etc are compatible to use? I am getting INFO like multiple Scala version detected. I am using Deequ LATEST or tried with some other latest versions too. I am getting multiple version of Scala that may be primary reason of issue. Please help if you can provide the correct pom file and compatible version of all.

Below is the Info, Error and used POM.xml :

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.1.3:compile (scala-compile-first) @ test-dq-framework ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.11:0.9.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.0 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING]  org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:3.5.3 requires scala version: 2.11.11
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/java8/JFunction1$mcZD$sp
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcZD$sp
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

POM.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>dq-test</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.package.name</groupId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <properties>
    <revision>0.1</revision>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazon.deequ</groupId>
      <artifactId>deequ</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0_spark-2.4-scala-2.11</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
      <artifactId>config</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipMain>true</skipMain> <!-- skip compile -->
          <skip>true</skip> <!-- skip testCompile -->
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>className</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

At Maven Repository you have the compile dependencies to this version of Amazon Deequ used: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.deequ/deequ/1.1.0_spark-2.4-scala-2.11

It's showing spark-core_2.11 version 2.4.2, spark-sql_2.11 version 2.4.2 and scala-library version 2.11.10.

Maybe adjust the spark-core version at your pom.xml and add the following dependency of scala-library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @importa, your info is helpful bur changes the Scala version, the new issue is related to fasterxml version, I have tried with 2.11, 2.12.* but it says that incompatible version, not getting what is the suitable version of Jackson to use.